# Getting error: Authentication with the CRM provider failed, while creating sfdc instance through cloudelements

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying to create an element instance in cloudelements. Have retrieved the code parameter from the url query string, have following codebase:

```
$ch = curl_init();  

$code = $_REQUEST['code'];

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: User xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzz=, Organization ccccccccccccccccccccccccc'
);

$url = 'https://api.cloud-elements.com/elements/api-v2/elements/23/instances';

$curl_post_data = array(
    "providerData" => array(
        "code" => $code
    ),
    "name" => "salesforce_instance_".date("Y-m-d-H:i:s"),
    "configuration" =>
        array(
            "base.url" => "https://login.salesforce.com",
            "filter.response.nulls" => "true"
        )
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But, i am getting following error:

```
Authentication with the CRM provider failed. Please ensure valid authentication values were provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the header part. Please check your 'Authorisation' field in the header. It is a formatted string. So the spaces and commas are countable. It is better to copy-paste from their UI itself.

You can get the authorisation header from their 'api try it out' page. To enter to that screen first login to cloud elements. Then press the 'API Docs' button. It will direct you to the page - https://my.cloudelements.io/api-docs/platform . Then select some option from left side. For example 'Elements'. Then there you can see a set of endpoints over the right side. Select one from there, say /elements/{keyOrId}/instances. Then press on the 'Try it out ' button. On the authorisation field , you can get the header value. Copy- paste it in your code.

Thank you